# curl init location ist automatically edited on second try

Tags: php, curl

I have a foreach-statement in php that loads some data from a database for each entry and sends it to a specific address:

```
foreach ($affiliates['response']['data'] as $aff_id => $data) {
    $curl_connection =
            curl_init('https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm');

    //set options
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    ...

    //traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
    foreach ($post_data as $key => $value) {
        $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
    }

    //create the final string to be posted using implode()
    $post_string = implode('&', $post_items);

    //set data to be posted
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

    //perform our request
    $result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

    //show information regarding the request
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
    echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' .
    curl_error($curl_connection);
    echo '</pre>';

    //close the connection
    curl_close($curl_connection);

}
```

The result is that the first entry is made correctly but the following ones are missing.
I printed out the curl-messages and realized that the link I enter in curl_init is different from the second try on.

It first looks like:

> https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm

And then it is edited to

> https://www.zoho.com/crm/

Do I have to set some other options or did I set some of them wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Option1:**

try to unset $curl_connection at the beginning of the for loop

the first two lines will become:

```
foreach ($affiliates['response']['data'] as $aff_id => $data) {
    unset( $curl_connection );
    $curl_connection = curl_init('https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm');
...
```

**option 2**
since you are connecting to the same url in your curl_init, you can connect before looping. i.e.

```
$curl_connection = curl_init('https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm');
foreach ($affiliates['response']['data'] as $aff_id => $data) {
...
```

Comment: Hey I gave it a shot but it did not work. In the end I used the Zoho-Api instead which allows me to send more than one set of data with a single post.
Thank you